# Where to declare views in android studio java code? Whether the declaration should be done outside or inside onCreate function

Tags: java, android, view, declaration, findviewbyid

> I have a confusion regarding declarations. In the first code I have declared **views** inside the **onCreate** function whereas in second code I have declared outside the **onCreate**
> function. The first code is working well whereas second one is not working. I don't know which one is correct. In my some other projects I have declared outside **onCreate** function but there is no any problem. But why there is problem.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//This declaration
        TextView imgNum=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView frame =  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView left= findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView right=findViewById(R.id.imageView3);


        left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count--;
                if (count<0){
                    count+=9;
                }
            }
```

> But this is not working. The only change I have done is I have put all the declaration outside **onCreate** function.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count=0;

//this declaration
        TextView imgNum=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView frame =  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView left= findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView right=findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count--;
                if (count<0){
                    count+=9;
                }
```

> Please help me out

Comment: My guess here is that the views have not been loaded yet and therefore they aren't initialised. I'm not 100% sure though. Have you tried something like `System.out.println(imgNum + " | " + frame + " | " + left + " | " + right);` to see what values they have (if they are null or not)?

Answer (score 0):

The first method is the correct one. Your second method declares the `Views` before the `Activity` is `created` (`onCreate`) which most probably will result in `app crash` because the `Activity` hasn't yet been `created`. If the `Activity` is not `created`, then the `view elements` inside it can't be `declared` or accessed until the `activity` is `created`.